# get file from input type 'file' and move into specific folder using jquery (without using form tag and submit button)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Below is my HTML, JQUERY and PHP code.

How to get file in specific folder or project directory using jQuery without using form tag and submit button.

I have created an html page and this `<div>` is in my html page. I want to upload two icons or image file and store it to my project directory or in `img` folder using jQuery and AJAX.

**html:**

```
<div id="serve" class="col-md-6" style="display: none;">
<span class="col-md-6"><h3> Add Service Details</h3></span><br><br>
<span>Select Icon for Service : </span>&nbsp;<input type="file" id="icon" class="form-control pad">
<input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title" class="form-control pad" />
<textarea rows="5" id="desc" class="form-control pad" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
<span>Select Icon for Description : </span>&nbsp;<input type="file" id="icondesc" class="form-control pad">
<button id="adds" class="btn primary-btn">Add</button>
```

**jquery:**

```
$('#adds').click(function(){
        var filename = $('#icon').val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, 'img\\');
        var extension = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        var icon = filename.replace(filename, $.now() + '.' + extension);
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var desc = $('#desc').val();
        var filename1 = $('#icondesc').val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, 'img\\');
        var extension1 = filename1.substr(filename1.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        var descicon = filename1.replace(filename1, $.now() + '.' + extension1);

        // uploadFile();
        $.post('indexaction.php',{
            icon: icon,
            title: title,
            desc: desc,
            descicon: descicon
        }, function(data){
            // var data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            $('#showservice').show();
            $('#showportfolio').hide();
            $('#serve').hide();
            $('#port').hide();
            $(function() {
                    $.each(data, function(index,data){
                        var someRow = "<div> "+data.icon+" </div><br><div> "+data.title+" </div><br><div> "+data.description+" </div><br><div> "+data.descicon+" </div><br>"; 
                        $('#showservice').html(someRow);
                    })
                });
        },'json');

    })
```

**indexaction.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['icon'])){

$icon =  $_POST['icon'];
$dir = "img/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$icon]["tmp_name"], $dir. $_FILES[$icon]["name"]);
$descicon =  $_POST["descicon"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$descicon]["tmp_name"], $dir. $_FILES[$descicon]["name"]);

$insert = "insert into service values('','".$icon."','".$_POST['title']."','".$_POST['desc']."','".$descicon."')";
mysqli_query($con, $insert);

$select = "select * from service";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$select);
$dataabc = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    $dataabc[] = $row;
echo json_encode($dataabc);
```

}

Comment: What **exactly** does not work with all that code?

Comment: file can't store into img folder

Comment: And what happens instead? Have you tried debugging your code? Are there any error messages logged?

Comment: only file name is stored in database

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: i used different codes from internet but didn't work.

Comment: So you have not tried to add some `var_dump` calls to see whether your variables are set to the proper values, set a higher level of `error_reporting` to see whether errors occur, you have not looked to the server's error log to watch out for logged errors,....? Then you should start doing that :)

Comment: how to use var_dump and error_reporting?

Comment: Just have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display and php.net/var_dump - that's basic skills for PHP

Comment: i used   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);                 no error show